# Couchbase Template Version 1.4.2

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

In the AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration Java

```
 protected FieldNamingStrategy fieldNamingStrategy() {
return abbreviateFieldNames() ? new CamelCaseAbbreviatingFieldNamingStrategy() : PropertyNameFieldNamingStrategy.INSTANCE;
```

}

Intelij can not resolve : FieldNamingStrategy and 
CamelCaseAbbreviatingFieldNamingStrategy() : PropertyNameFieldNamingStrategy.INSTANCE;

Thus i am getting the Folloing Stack Trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mapping/model/FieldNamingStrategy
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2398)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1838)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:447)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:317)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:125)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:98)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:358)
... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.FieldNamingStrategy
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
... 59 more
```

My POM conatins as follows:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-couchbase</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

What can be Done?

Comment: These 3 imports could not be found: import org.springframework.data.mapping.model.CamelCaseAbbreviatingFieldNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.data.mapping.model.FieldNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PropertyNameFieldNamingStrategy;

Comment: that is weird. from [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mapping/model/CamelCaseAbbreviatingFieldNamingStrategy.html) it has been there since spring-data-commons 1.9. Can you see the commons artifact in external libraries in IntelliJ? Should be `org.springframework.data`:`spring-data-commons`:`1.11.2.RELEASE`